# Use of one column from one table and equal with one input in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want that `sms_code` value from verify table equal that `$value` from parameter

```php
public function activateAccount($id, $value)
{
    $userSms = verify_sms::where('user_id', $id)->select('sms_code')->first();
    if ($value == $userSms) {
        //some code
        return 'ok';
    } else {
        // some code
        return 'no';
    }
}
```

and my answer is :

```
no
```

and my API URL is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/active/6/123456
```

Though `$id` and `$value` are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($value == $userSms->sms_code) {
  //some code
} else {
  // some code
}
```

Access the `sms_code` property from the queried `$userSms` object

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as like below. Compare the `$value` with `$userSms->sms_code`

```php
public function activateAccount($id, $value)
{
    $userSms = verify_sms::where('user_id', $id)->select('sms_code')->first();
    if ($value == $userSms->sms_code) {
        //some code
    } else {
        // some code
    }
    return 'ok';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
public function activateAccount($id, $value)
{
    $userSms = verify_sms::where('user_id', $id)->select('sms_code')->first();
    if ($value == $userSms->sms_code) {
        return 'ok';
    } else {
        return 'no';
    }
}
```